# Replace symbols in file c#

Tags: c#, arrays, file, text, input

> Hey, I'm trying to replace some symbols in file.  I made dictionary
>   and I can replace it in my string that I input. How to read my file,
>   do my replace and save it to another?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Translit translit = new Translit();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("test.txt");                       
        string testIn = "iconb ";  //a test input string         
        string testOut = translit.TranslitFileName(testIn);
        Console.WriteLine("Inputed \'{0}\'", testIn);
        Console.WriteLine("after \'{0}\'", testOut);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class Translit
    {

        Dictionary<string, string> dictionaryChar = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"а","a"},             
            {"е","e"},                                                                                   
            {"о","o"},              
            {"р","p"},
            {"с","c"}
        };

        public string TranslitFileName(string source)
        {
            var result = "";
            //symbols for replace 
            foreach (var ch in source)
            {
                var ss = "";      
                //compare dictionary keys                   
                if (dictionaryChar.TryGetValue(ch.ToString(), out ss))
                {
                    result += ss;
                }

                else result += ch;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To make it easier for answerers, or others with similar problems, please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: Each KeyValuePair in the Dictionary has same Key and Value, so seems useless. What's more, why replace character by character, just replace all the file content string at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing it this way:

```
Func<string, string> map = new []
{
    new { input = 'a', output = 'x' },
    new { input = 'e', output = 'x' },
    new { input = 'o', output = 'x' },
    new { input = 'p', output = 'x' },
    new { input = 'c', output = 'x' },
}
    .Select(x => (Func<string, string>)(s => s.Replace(x.input, x.output)))
    .Aggregate((f0, f1) => x => f1(f0(x)));

File.WriteAllText("output.text", map(File.ReadAllText("test.txt")));
```

Calling `map("Hello")` produces `"Hxllx"` given my `map` code above.

Comment: But also not easy to understand.